# One-way-sync a directory, but leave deleted files deleted on the destination

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I want to sync a directory between two systems. To make it more interesting the syncing must only be done in one direction, i.e.:

- if a file is deleted in the source directory, it must also be deleted in the destination, if it was previously transfered
- deleted files in the destination directory must not be deleted in the source
- partially transfered files (e.g. because of network problems) must be finished on the next sync
- new files in the source directory must be transfered to the destination
- **deleted files in the destination directory must not be re-transfered**

That means the source system has basically a master role, except that deleted files in the destination will not be forced back.

Both Linux systems have rsync/ssh/scp available.

New files in the source directory are created in such a way that one can use their mtime to detect them, e.g.:

```
if mtime(file) > date-of-last-sync then: it is a new file that needs to be transfered
```

Also, existing files are not changed in the source directory, i.e. the sync does not need to check for differences in already (completely) transfered files.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer at the moment but it sounds like you're looking for `rsync`.

Comment: @terdon, yes, but the challenge is that `rsync` would (by default) re-transfer files which were deleted from the destination directory.

Comment: Sorry, I had only glanced at your question and did not notice you had mentioned `rsync` nor the full breadth of your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not going to use the remote file system as the data source of what has been transferred then you need to externally track the files that have been successfully transferred previously, then exclude them from future transfers.

[`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) can include and exclude files based on *patterns* in a file so you can include a specific list of files in a transfer. Then exclude that list from future transfers.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

track_dir=~/.track_xfer
inc_file="$track_dir/include_files"
exc_file="$track_dir/exclude_files"
xfer_dir=~/testrsync
xfer_dest=~/testrsync_dest

mkdir -p "$track_dir"
touch $exc_file
cd "$xfer_dir"

# find files and create rsync filter list
find . -type f -print0 | perl -e '
  $/="\0"; 
  while (<>){ 
   chomp; 
   $_ =~ s!^\.!!;    # remove leading .
   $f = quotemeta;   # quote special chars
   $f =~ s!\\/!/!g;  # fix quoted paths `/`
   print $f."\n"; 
  }' > "$inc_file"

# Run the rsync
rsync -va --delete --exclude-from "$exc_file" --include-from "$inc_file" "$xfer_dir/" "$xfer_dest"

# Add the included/transferred files to the exclusion list
cat "$inc_file" "$exc_file" > "$exc_file".tmp
sort "$exc_file".tmp | uniq > "$exc_file"
```

You might need some more `rsync` specific regex quoting but the Perl [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function and replacements was the first easy solution that came to mind.

The main problem will be dealing with any special characters in files names. 
If you want to deal with new lines or tabs and other strange things in the names then you will have to put a bit more work into the `perl` (or whatever) that parses and generates the inclusion pattern list. If you can restrict the names of your transfer files to a simple character set then you don't need to worry about this step as much. The `perl` is a halfway solution that should get you past most common regex chars.

The reason for using the include list rather than letting `rsync` pull the whole directory it self is so that you have a defined/complete list of files for the subsequent exclude list. You could probably achieve the same result by parsing the `rsync` output or a `--log-file=FILE` for the files that were transferred but that looked a little harder.

Answer (score -1):

Rsync will do exactly what you want with `rsync -a --delete` (add `-x` if you need xattrs for example for selinux).

Rsync will never delete files in the source, but `--delete` will delete all files in destination that do not exist in the source.

It will update partially transferred files by the delta updating mechanism.
AFAIR rsync will check mtime (+file size) first and only if there is a mismatch the fingerprinting and delta-updating will be done.

Comment: This will re-transfer files deleted from the destination directory, the OP stated that is not appropriate.

Comment: if --delete is added to rsync it will transfer the files to the destination. it will not fulfill the question

Answer (score -2):

Please read the man page, as it should answer all your questions.  The command `man rsync` should display the man page.

rsync will verify that files are not changed.  It is extremely efficient at doing this and has never significantly slowed the rsync times for my transfers.  You can estimate the time it will take by timing a run of rsync immediately after the last run.

rsync is a one way sync and will not alter the source.  You can safely use a userid which can only read the source file, but has no write privileges.  However, this is not necessary.

rsync will recover any partially completed transfers when you rerun it.

rsync will only delete files on the destinations if you use one of delete options.

EDIT: To prevent re-transfer of files deleted from the destination directory, you would need to create an exclude list for those files.  This will exclude them from transfers even if they are updated.  Alternatively, you could truncate the files rather than deleting them and use the `--update` flag.  Files which are updated after you truncate them will be copied.

You may find an using an incremental tar backup does what you want better.  It is possible to use pipe the output of one tar to another over an ssh connection.  This will pick up any files created or modified since the last backup, but not transfer any other files.

Comment: and how to avoid re-transfers of files deleted in the destination directory?

Comment: @maxschlepzig See my edit for three options. (One is to use a tool more appropriate for incremental transfers.)  Rsync is not designed to automatically handle your use case.